# JPanel does not paintComponent in specific circumstance

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am creating a program that will create a window with a fairly simple but multicomponent GUI. I tested the JPanel logic by creating a sample with just the panel in a frame and it works fine, however when creating the JPanel within my real GUI, only the background shows.

Code for BoardPanel:

```
package groupchatclient;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BoardPanel extends JPanel
{
    int xOff = 20,yOff = 20,height = 20,width = 50,size = 30;
    char orientation = 'V';
    public BoardPanel()
    {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    }
    public BoardPanel(int height, char orient, int size, int width)
    {
        this.height = height;
        orientation = orient;
        this.size = size;
        this.width = width;
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        int xOffset,yOffset;
        if(Character.toUpperCase(orientation) == 'V')
        {   

            for(int h = 0; h<height; h++)
            {

                if(h%2 == 0)
                {


                    for(int w = 0; w<width; w++)
                    {

                        //find the top point
                        xOffset = xOff + w*(int)(Math.sqrt(3)*size);
                        yOffset = yOff + (h*3*size/2);
                        Point hexPoint = new Point(xOffset,yOffset);
                        //calculate the other points
                        VertHex hex = new VertHex(hexPoint,size);
                        //organize the points into a usable format
                        int[] xPoints = new int[6];
                        int[] yPoints = new int[6];
                        for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
                        {
                            xPoints[i] = hex.getPoint(i).getX();
                            yPoints[i] = hex.getPoint(i).getY();
                        }
                        //print the hexagon
                        g.drawPolygon(xPoints,yPoints,6);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int w = 0; w<width-1; w++)
                    {
                     //find the top point
                     xOffset = xOff + w*(int)(Math.sqrt(3)*size) + (int)(size*Math.sqrt(3)/2);
                     yOffset = yOff + (h*3*size/2);
                     Point hexPoint = new Point(xOffset,yOffset);
                     //calculate the other points
                     VertHex hex = new VertHex(hexPoint,size); 
                    //organize the points into a usable format
                     int[] xPoints = new int[6];
                     int[] yPoints = new int[6];
                     for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
                     {
                         xPoints[i] = hex.getPoint(i).getX();
                         yPoints[i] = hex.getPoint(i).getY();
                     }
                     //print the hexagon
                     g.drawPolygon(xPoints,yPoints,6);
                    }
                } 

            }
        }
        else //FLAT ORIENTATION
        {
            for(int w = 0; w<width; w++)
            {

                if(w%2 == 0)
                {


                    for(int h = 0; h<height; h++)
                    {

                        //find the top left point
                       xOffset = xOff + (int)(w*3*size/2);
                       yOffset = yOff + (int)(h*Math.sqrt(3)*size);
                        Point hexPoint = new Point(xOffset,yOffset);
                        //calculate the other points
                        FlatHex hex = new FlatHex(hexPoint,size);
                        //organize the points into a usable format
                        int[] xPoints = new int[6];
                        int[] yPoints = new int[6];
                        for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
                        {
                            xPoints[i] = hex.getPoint(i).getX();
                            yPoints[i] = hex.getPoint(i).getY();
                        }
                        //print the hexagon
                        g.drawPolygon(xPoints,yPoints,6);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int h = 0; h<height-1; h++)
                    {
                     //find the top left point
                     xOffset = xOff + (int)(w*3*size/2);
                     yOffset = yOff + (int)(h*Math.sqrt(3)*size + Math.sqrt(3)*size/2);
                     Point hexPoint = new Point(xOffset,yOffset);
                     //calculate the other points
                     FlatHex hex = new FlatHex(hexPoint,size); 
                    //organize the points into a usable format
                     int[] xPoints = new int[6];
                     int[] yPoints = new int[6];
                     for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
                     {
                         xPoints[i] = hex.getPoint(i).getX();
                         yPoints[i] = hex.getPoint(i).getY();
                     }
                     //print the hexagon
                     g.drawPolygon(xPoints,yPoints,6);
                    }
                } 

            }
        }
    }
    public void setOrientation(char c)
    {
        if(c == 'v' || c == 'V' || c == 'h' || c == 'H')
        {
            orientation = c;
        }
    }
}
```

Code for BoardFrame:

```
package groupchatclient;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BoardFrame extends JFrame
{

    public BoardFrame(BufferedReader in, PrintWriter out, int height, char orient, int size, int width)
    {
        super("Pentarius");
        initComponents();
        this.out = out;
        this.in = in;
        this.height = height;
        this.orient = orient;
        this.size = size;
        this.width = width;
    }

     private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        mainScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        mainDisplayPane = new BoardPanel(height, orient, size, width);
        filler1 = new javax.swing.Box.Filler(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 10), new java.awt.Dimension(0, 10), new java.awt.Dimension(32767, 10));
        searchScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        searchTextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        chatTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        chatScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        chatTextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        searchTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(mainDisplayPane);
        mainDisplayPane.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 817, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 622, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        mainScrollPane.setViewportView(mainDisplayPane);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(mainScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 809, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(filler1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(6, 6, 6))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(filler1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(mainScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 613, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        searchTextArea.setColumns(20);
        searchTextArea.setRows(5);
        searchScrollPane.setViewportView(searchTextArea);

        chatTextField.setText("");
        chatTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                out.println(chatTextField.getText());
                chatTextField.setText("");
            }
        });

        chatTextArea.setColumns(20);
        chatTextArea.setRows(5);
        chatScrollPane.setViewportView(chatTextArea);

        searchTextField.setText("");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(searchScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(chatScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(searchTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(chatTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 5, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(searchScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 252, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(searchTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(chatScrollPane)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(chatTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PentariusFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PentariusFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PentariusFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PentariusFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new PentariusFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    public void setFiller(javax.swing.Box.Filler fill) {
        filler1 = fill;
    }
    public void setPanel1(javax.swing.JPanel panel) {
        jPanel1 = panel;
    }
    public void setMainDisplayPane(javax.swing.JPanel panel) {
        mainDisplayPane = panel;
    }
    public void setSearchScrollPane(javax.swing.JScrollPane scroll) {
        searchScrollPane = scroll;
    }
    public void setChatScrollPane(javax.swing.JScrollPane scroll) {
        chatScrollPane = scroll;
    }
    public void setMainScrollPane(javax.swing.JScrollPane scroll) {
        mainScrollPane = scroll;
    }
    public void setSearchTextArea(javax.swing.JTextArea area) {
        searchTextArea = area;
    }
    public void setChatTextArea(javax.swing.JTextArea area) {
        chatTextArea = area;
    }
    public void setChatTextField(javax.swing.JTextField field) {
        chatTextField = field;
    }
    public void setSearchTextField(javax.swing.JTextField field) {
        searchTextField = field;
    }

    public javax.swing.Box.Filler getFiller() {
        return filler1;
    }
    public javax.swing.JPanel getMainDisplayPane() {
        return mainDisplayPane;
    }
    public javax.swing.JPanel getJPanel1() {
        return jPanel1;
    }
    public javax.swing.JScrollPane getSearchScrollPane() {
        return searchScrollPane;
    }
    public javax.swing.JScrollPane getChatScrollPane() {
        return chatScrollPane;
    }
    public javax.swing.JScrollPane getMainScrollPane() {
        return mainScrollPane;
    }
    public javax.swing.JTextArea getSearchTextArea() {
        return searchTextArea;
    }
    public javax.swing.JTextArea getChatTextArea() {
        return chatTextArea;
    }
    public javax.swing.JTextField getSearchTextField() {
        return searchTextField;
    }
    public javax.swing.JTextField getChatTextField() {
        return chatTextField;
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.Box.Filler filler1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel mainDisplayPane;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane searchScrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane chatScrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane mainScrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea searchTextArea;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea chatTextArea;
    private javax.swing.JTextField chatTextField;
    private javax.swing.JTextField searchTextField;

    private final PrintWriter out;
    private final BufferedReader in;
    private final int height;
    private final int size;
    private final char orient;
    private final int width;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Code for draw method which creates the GUI:

```
public void draw(GroupChatClient client) throws Exception
    {
                frame.setVisible(false);
        BoardFrame bf = new BoardFrame(in,out,bp.height,bp.orientation,bp.size,bp.width);
        bf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        if(bp.orientation == 'V')
        {
            panelSizeX=2*(int)(bp.width*Math.sqrt(3)*bp.size/2);
            panelSizeY= 2*bp.yOff + 2*bp.size*bp.height;
        }
        else //orientation = FLAT
        {
            panelSizeX= 2*(bp.yOff)+ (bp.size*bp.width);
            panelSizeY= 2*(int)(bp.height*Math.sqrt(3)*bp.size/2);
        }
        System.out.println(panelSizeX + " " + panelSizeY);
        bf.getChatTextArea().setEditable(false);
        bf.getSearchTextArea().setEditable(false);

        DefaultCaret newCaret = (DefaultCaret)bf.getChatTextArea().getCaret();
        newCaret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);

        bf.getChatTextArea().setLineWrap(true);
        bf.getSearchTextArea().setLineWrap(true);

        //bf.getChatTextField().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        //    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //        out.println(bf.getChatTextField().getText());
        //        bf.getChatTextField().setText("");
        //    }
        //});

        bf.pack();
        bf.setVisible(true);
        while(true)
        {
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) 
            {
                bf.getChatTextArea().append(line.substring(8) + "\n");
            }
        }
            }
```

I have been testing this without altering any qualities of bp, which is initialized as a new default boardpanel

Comment: Without a runnable example which demonstrates your problem, it's going to be hard to diagnose your issue.  However, I really, really, really think you need to have a read of [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). Swing is single thread AND not thread safe. So this means you shouldn't do anything that would block the EDT (like running never ending loops) and you should not update the UI from out side the context of the EDT - that's why I recommended you ave a look at `SwingWorker` earlier.

Comment: The `while(true)` is scary or a number of reasons - it could be blocking the EDT, if it's not, then you're violating the single threaded nature of the API

Comment: I know you're right and I'm just being lazy. I'll read through it now and implement it into this program. As for this problem, a runnable example is gonna be tricky. let me see if i can narrow the problem down to some quicker code. It will take a while though as i work on the concurrency issue